# error in libcrypto при подключении по ssh из командной строки

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

При подключении по ssh через терминал в убунту командой

```
ssh -i '/home/xxx/.ssh/logsKeys/xxx.ppk' logview@xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

получаю ошибку

```
Load key "/home/xxx/.ssh/logsKeys/xxx.ppk": error in libcrypto
logview@xxx.xxx.xx.xx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

При чем через путти всё подключается нормально. Система Ubuntu 22.04

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Очевидно, ppk это формат специфичный для путти, и обычный ssh совершенно не обязан его поддерживать https://www.tune-it.ru/web/jek/blog/-/blogs/polucaem-openssh-kluci-iz-fajla-ppk-pod-linux